# For all prime numbers $ \ a,b,c \ , a^{2} + b^{2} \neq c^{2}$ 3 (solution inside)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

[image: Solution]

[image: Solution_pt2]

Hey guys, I'm trying to figure out how this solution is moving forward, so far so good, but this specific line (which I've highlighted in the attached picture) makes like no sense. Does anyone have an idea what they are trying to say?

Comment: Odd (prime) numbers $c,b$ give $c+b$ and $c-b$ even. Their product is even, which cannot be equal to $a^2$, which is odd. The case $b=2$ is the same as $a=2$. The case $c=2$ you can check just by plugging the few cases in which the LHS is not larger than $4$. It is true that the line that you highlighted is not clear.

Comment: Owwh, thank you good sir @noodlesGroup :)

Comment: For Pythagorean theorem to hold, either a or b must be even,which allows only 2.  Assume a=2 then (c-b)(c+b)=4, while each term in the product is even (b and c both odd), leading to c+b=c-b=2 - impossible!

Comment: Thank you @herbsteinberg !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a=b$. Then $2a^2=c^2$, which is impossible. Thus, without loss of generality, you can assume $a<b$. It also holds that $a<c$ and $b<c$. Then $a^2=(c-b)(c+b)$. Since $b$ and $c$ must be odd, the only possibility is that $a=2$. Thus
$$
(c-b)(c+b)=4
$$
However, $b\ge3$ and $c\ge3$, so $c+b\ge6$.

Comment: Thank you @egreg !